# How do I insert Java variables into query through textfields?

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to create a register system for my MySQL database. I have a Java form that I created, in which the user inserts a username, password, and their email. I take that infromation and store it in a variable accordingly. The MySQL connection code works, and it does insert a new row, but the information is blank on the MySQL page. Am I doing someting wrong?

```
public class Main extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField textField;
private JPasswordField passwordField;

private static Connection con;
private static PreparedStatement st;
private static int rs;

String username;
String password;
String email;
private JTextField textField_1;

String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO `users`" + "(username, password, email) VALUES" + "(?,?,?)";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Main frame = new Main();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public Main() {
    setResizable(false);
    setTitle("Barrage : Login / Register");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 350, 200);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Username: ");
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(60, 25, 68, 20);
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);

    JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Password: ");
    lblPassword.setBounds(60, 59, 68, 20);
    contentPane.add(lblPassword);

    textField = new JTextField();
    username = textField.getText();
    textField.setBounds(138, 22, 120, 26);
    contentPane.add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    passwordField = new JPasswordField();
    password = passwordField.getText();
    passwordField.setBounds(138, 56, 120, 26);
    contentPane.add(passwordField);

    JButton btnRegister = new JButton("Register");
    btnRegister.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try{
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/barrage", "root", "");
                st = con.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);
                st.setString(1, username);
                st.setString(2, password);
                st.setString(3, email);
                st.executeUpdate();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });
    btnRegister.setBounds(119, 138, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnRegister);

    JLabel lblEmail = new JLabel("E-mail: ");
    lblEmail.setBounds(60, 96, 68, 20);
    contentPane.add(lblEmail);

    textField_1 = new JTextField();
    email = textField_1.getText();
    textField_1.setBounds(138, 93, 120, 26);
    contentPane.add(textField_1);
    textField_1.setColumns(10);
}
```

}

Comment: You need to assign values to the three parameter variables **inside** you `actionPerformed` method.  So you will need 3 separate `JTextField` components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the values of `username` u.a. in the moment where you you call the `actionPerformed` method.

Right now you set the value when creating the GUI. At that moment they are `null`. They are not "linked", they just take the value that the controls return at that time. If the controls `getText()` result changes, your variables do not get updated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the various fields' `getText()` method in your `ActionListener` so that you get the values after the user has entered them.

As it stands now you get the initial values prior to any user interaction.